# Cant read value of x in another function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make `obj1.print` print 9, but it gives me `undefined`. Here is my code

```
var obj1 = {
    x: 9,
    print1: function() {
        util.print();
    }
}

var util = {
    print: function() {
        console.log(this.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Console.log(obj1.x); would work better I guess. In that context `this` refers to `util` and not to `obj1`. And `util` doesn't have any `x` property so it gives you undefined.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `this` statement in the util reference to the current scope `this`, in other words when you call `util.print()` calling `obj1.print1()` the this statement is bind to the `window`. so when you call to `this.x` is undefined because you didn't define `x` in `top` a.k.a. `window`

so to solve your issue you can use the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function. by doing that you define the `this` of the scope function as the `obj1` so when you call to `util.print` the `this` scope of the function is `obj1`

```
var obj1 = {
    x: 9,
    print1: function(){
        util.print.apply(this);
    }
}

var util = {
    print: function(){
        console.log(this.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the OP code, `this` is not bound to the window but to the util variable in that context.

Comment: This seems to be a workaround/hack to solve a problem which is actually conceptual in nature.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in some comments, when you use `this` in your `util.print` function, it refers to the `util` object that doesn't have a property called `x`.

[Zamboney answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35968155/5994091) is working fine but I think it lacks of clarity. In my opinion, changing the meaning of `this` is not the way to go and may be confusing later on.

I would rather pass the object to the `util.print` function like so.

```js
var obj1 = {
  x: 9,
  print1: function() {
    util.print(this);
  }
}

var util = {
  print: function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.x);
  }
}

obj1.print1();
```